# How to install Vim plugins in Fedora 16

Tags: vim, plugins, fedora

I installed Vim in Fedora 16 with this command:

```
$ yum -y install vim-enhanced
```

Vim works just fine, but now I wanted to add the NERD Commenter and NERD Tree plugins. In the home directory I cant find neither `.vim/` nor `.vimrc`. So I went ahead and created those but still it's not picking it up.

How do you install Vim plugins in Fedora?

Comment: that is the problem . ~/.vim/ directory was not created automatically. I created it manually but still vim is not picking it up.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with creating the `.vim` directory and the `.vimrc` file. You just need to do a bit more to get Vim to load the plugins. Try my answer for one way to add plugins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create `~/.vimrc` and `~/.vim/` yourself.

After that simply follow each plugin's installation instructions.

For NERDTree (from the plugin's page):

```
Unzip the archive into your ~/.vim directory. 
That should put NERD_tree.vim in ~/.vim/plugin and NERD_tree.txt in ~/.vim/doc. 
Run :helptags. 
Go :help NERD_tree.txt for the help page.
```

After all that, you are supposed to end up with this structure:

```
~/.vim/doc/NERD_tree.txt
~/.vim/doc/tags
~/.vim/nerdtree_plugin/exec_menuitem.vim
~/.vim/nerdtree_plugin/fs_menu.vim
~/.vim/plugin/NERD_tree.vim
~/.vim/syntax/nerdtree.vim
```

Which is all you need to use NERDTree:

```
:NERDTree<CR>
```

Did you try the "built-in" `netrw`, invoked with `:Ex` (`:Hex`,`:Sex`,`:Vex`…), before deciding to install NERDTree?

Comment: I just knew about Sex . The reasons I use NerdTree is that it open the file in full window and not in split window. I use CNTRL + 6 to switch between the files loaded in buffer

Answer (score 3):

The fact that your distribution is Fedora should be largely irrelevant. The install process is the same for any GNU/Linux distribution.

I recommend you manage your plugins with Tim Pope's [Pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen). Install Pathogen to your .vim directory per the [instructions in the README](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen#installation). Then, edit your .vimrc to run Pathogen on startup (again, see the [README](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen#runtime-path-manipulation)).

Then, with Pathogen installed, you can add any plugin to the directory `.vim/bundle`, and it'll load automatically.

Vim's plugin management is pretty crummy, and Pathogen fills the much-needed role of a plugin manager. It's wildly popular, and pretty simple.

Comment: Installing vim did not create ~/.vim and .vimrc in my home directory. It is strange

Comment: That's perfectly normal, to my knowledge. You don't need either for Vim to run, they're just for customization purposes. You did the right thing by creating them yourself.